# C++: covert int to unsigned char

Tags: c++, int

I declared an IP address:

```
int test_ip = (192) | (168<<8) | (33<<16) | (255<<24);
```

Then I need to convert it to (unsigned char*). I trying to do this:

```
(u_char*)test_ip
```

I use VS 2010 C++ debugger in order to evaluate the last expression. Debugger's output for this expression:

```
0xff21a8c0 <Bad Ptr>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why Bad Ptr?

Comment: Your error was you converted the IP address to a pointer, not the address of `test_ip`.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't really looking for `inet_ntoa`?

Answer (score 2):

Your conversion better be done by in_addr data type:

*This is the windows in_addr so if you want to use it on linux you'll have to re-declare it with other name.*

```
typedef struct in_addr {
  union {
    struct {
      u_char s_b[4];
    } S_un_b;
    struct {
      u_short s_w[2];
    } S_un_w;
    u_long S_addr;
  } S_un;
};
```

like this:

```
in_addr address;
address.S_addr = (192) | (168<<8) | (33<<16) | (255<<24);
```

`address.S_un_b.s_b`  is ready now, with array of 4 bytes representing the address...

Comment: No. No. No. Might not work due to structure packing. An array would work though.

Comment: `S_addr` is `u_long` but I need the whole IP address in one `u_char` variable.

Comment: Now it should work. since arrays doesn't have alignment. and you can get the pointer

Comment: Yup, this is now perfect, plus one

Answer (score 1):

Attempting a c-style cast will give you undefined behaviour as the pointer types are unrelated. Your best bet is to use a static cast of the int, modulo 256.

```
unsigned char c = static_cast<unsigned char>(test_ip % 256)
```

This will be safe since the standard guarantees the size of an unsigned char as being 8 bits.

Once you've taken this cast to unsigned char, take the address of that as your pointer &c.

If you want other parts of test_ip then combine with integral division etc. Just take care not to overflow the unsigned char when taking the cast.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't understand :(

Comment: Which bit have I not explained well?

Comment: Do you mean this: `(u_char*)&test_ip` ?

Comment: You missed the type parameter off static cast, but otherwise this is sound advice.

Comment: @Gooman no, he means not to use the c style cast at all ((type)value), but the C++ static cast (static_cast<type>(value))

Comment: `If you want other parts of test_ip then combine with integral division etc.` What is integral division in C++?

Comment: Dividing an integer by another one: a remainder is discarded

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you need it as an `unsigned char*` to pass it to
some protocol.  In which case, you can't just cast, since the
bit representation of your `int` is not necessarily what the
protocol expects.  You have to extract it byte by byte, just as
you constructed it, placing the bytes in an `unsigned char`
buffer.